# No video device on chromebook

Tags: python, pygame, chromebook

I'm trying to code a game using pygame in googles colaboratory using pygame. I succesfully added pygame by running:

```
import os
!git clone https://github.com/ntasfi/PyGame-Learning-Environment.git
os.chdir('PyGame-Learning-Environment')
!pip install -e .
!pip install pygame
os.chdir('/content')
```

But when I wrote this code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
BLACK = [0,0,0]
size = [100,100]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size))
screen.fill(BLACK)
screen.update()

pygame.quit()
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-b26800e3009a> in <module>()
BLACK = [0,0,0]
size = [100,100]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((size)) 
screen.fill(BLACK)
```

**Error: No available video device**

Is there any way i can add make pygame detect the laptop screen?

Answer (score 1):

first of all try this

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
BLACK = (0, 0, 0) #dont use []'s
WIDTH = 0 #yourwidth
HEIGHT = 0 #yourheight
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT)) 
screen.fill(BLACK)
running = True
while(running):
 for event in pygame.event.get():
  if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
   running = False
```